Dark setting action fantasy anime; protagonist has white hair, wears black, slim clothes, and fights with his hand
I'm trying to remember the name of this anime: dark setting, action, fantasy. It was released a long time ago.
The protagonist has white hair (I think) and wears black, slim clothes. He fights with his hand (weapon hand, and I think it turned into a bigger and longer hand).
I think the girl protagonist had dark green hair with twin tails.
In a later scene, the protagonist plays piano music which makes him stronger.
I'm trying to remember the title of the anime to figure out that piano music.
Thank you. And I apologize for such a brief explanation.

Sounds like D.Gray-man to me:

It was released a long time ago (2005-ish?)

2)The protagonist has white hair Allen Walker and wears black, slim clothes. I've not seen the show for a while but as I remember he had some kind of curse linked to his hand that he fought with.
Lenalee Lee plays a major role and has dark green hair with twin tails.
Towards the end, Allen takes control of "The Ark", this can only be piloted by the piano which he learns from his guardian Mana.
Here's a picture

:)

It sounds like it could be Takt Op. The premise of the story is that there are monsters called D2s that can only be destroyed by human generated music.

The protagonist, Takt, is a talented pianist. ("He plays the piano")

Takt's right arm has the ability to become a powerful weapon which can transform into a conductor's baton. ("He fights with his hand")

Takt has black hair (not white) but does wear a form fitting tuxedo style suit. ("wears black, slim clothes")

There is a girl named Titan who has large pigtails that are red, but the tips are green. ("dark green hair with twin tails")


Trailer



